# Aligning staves across pages in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I'm looking for a way to align staves in Lilypond such that the bars are at the same height on different pages.

A somewhat contrived example to show the effect:

```
\version "2.24.0"

\paper {
  #(set-paper-size "a9")
  oddHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  evenHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  oddFooterMarkup = \markup \null
  evenFooterMarkup = \markup \null

  top-margin = 0.6\cm
  bottom-margin = 0\cm
  left-margin = 0.15\cm
}

{ \clef bass c }

\pageBreak

{ \clef bass a }

\pageBreak

{ \clef bass g }
```

[image: Non-aligned staves]

The `a` causes the bounding box of that staff to be extended, which makes the bars of the staves on both pages be of different height.

Comment: To answer my own question: One option in the cases shown here is to add a transparent object of the right height, e.g. `\once \override Staff.Clef.transparent = ##t` followed by `\clef treble`. Ideally I'd like to make its X-extent 0 though, and I'm not sure how to do that w/o changing the Y-extent.